# Online Assembly language resources

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86

does anyone have any resources for learning assembly language on x86? I'm trying to debug a program in MSVC++6 and frequently come across assembly (like stepping into memcpy).. Previously I just ignored these but memcpy keeps throwing exceptions and I need to find out why..

Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT:Wow, lots of great resources.. I wish I could mark everything as accepted answer :P

HINT: combine anyone? :P

New edit: I just looked through the answers, and these seemed the best:

Aseraphim's post [specific to intel x86](http://developer.intel.com/design/pentiumii/manuals/243191.htm)

jkchong's post [for a more introductory text](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/)

Comment: Upvote any you think are good answers

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation :S maybe if someone upvoted my question.. :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to understand what each instruction does, the reference manual for the IA-32 (x86) & IA64 instruction sets are located [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Answer (score 7):

Online resources:

[PC Assembly Language](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/)

[Art of Assembly Language Programming](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/index.html)

Comment: The first link here is nice.. Too bad I don't have enough reputation to vote it up.. :S

Comment: I'm fond of Art os Assembly Language Programming, and I did.

Answer (score 1):

[Dunteman's "Assembly Language Step by Step"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471375233) is a pretty good starting point for x86 assembly.

I'm sure there are good tutorial sites on the Net, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Wow! I read an earlier edition of that book about 15 years ago. If I remember correctly, it was very good.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I can't choose this as the correct answer because I cannot verify it, I'd need to get my hands on the book first :S

Answer (score 1):

We used [Microcomputer Experimentation with the IBM PC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0030095425) and [Assembly Language Step-By-Step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471578142) when I took it in school (back in the 1900s).  Both are pretty good introductory books.

Comment: I wore an onion on my belt, which was the style at the time.

Comment: Hey, everybody.  An old man's talking!

Comment: Haha.. I did not understand the "onion on my belt" thing.. XD

Comment: Isn't this the type of question SO mods love to close?

Comment: I upvote because a moderator with 188k reputation doesn't look good with any upvote. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are also two great communities about x86 assembly programming on Windows:

- [ascommunity.net](http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/)
- [masmforum.com](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?)

If you are specifically interested in Visual Studio and the MS assembler (masm), you'll want to look into [masmforum.com](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?).