# What are some good x86 assembly language resources?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

What are some good online resources (references, books, tutorials, documentation, etc) for learning and programming in assembly language (more specifically nasm)?  It seems as though some of assembly language is rather arcane and I sometimes have problems finding any good info on it.

Comment: The nasm manual looks fairly comprehensive. What do you need to know that isn't covered by that?

Comment: Nothing in particular.  It's just always helpful to have more resources.  Especially if the manual doesn't make any sense, because then I have something to compare it to.

Comment: I just found a question that this is an exact duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379977/online-assembly-language-resources - feel free to close this.

Answer (score 3):

The Art of Assembly Language online books are pretty useful. (Don't let the terrible website turn you off.)

http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/index.html

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.emu8086.com/ for a Windows-hosted 8086 emulator with assembler & tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple:

- [PC Assembly language](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/)
- [nasm manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/)

Answer (score 1):

Getting information from the horses mouth is always helpful with these kind of things. Check out the [Intel reference manual](http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/243191.htm).

Answer (score 1):

For x86 and GNU/Linux:
http://programminggroundup.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

Until NASM's version 2.05 the manual carried an appendix with an instruction reference. This was removed for being out of date though. Most notably, it doesn't describe any AMD64 instructions, apart from a brief listing of the REX prefixing in the beginning. I forked NASM into https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/insref and set up the resulting document at https://ulukai.org/ecm/insref.htm with a few additions (which are listed in the repo's history).

Answer (score 0):

Assembly Language Step-by-Step is really good. It's targeted directly at nasm.

If you can wait till October, a new edition is coming out to cover newer features, such as 64 bit, but the older one is still very relevant, especially for beginners.